# Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' to 'jacrs_ios.TopViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I'm new to Swift and I was trying to make a side menu base on the tutorial that I was following but I ran across with this error. "Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1026054a8) to 'jacrs_ios.TopViewController' (0x1009ac510)." I noticed that there were same problems already existing here but I still dont understand. I'm gonna included the current storyboard in case I did something wrong. Thanks.

**ViewController Error**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let topViewController = segue.destination as! TopViewController
    topViewController.stringPassed = userName.text!
}
```

**Storyboard**

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
{

 let topViewController = navigationController?.topViewController as! TopViewController
 topViewController.stringPassed = userName.text!

}
```

Comment: I tried something like this earlier, without the if statement but. It says "use of undeclared type UINavigationViewController"

Comment: It's UINavigationController not UINavigationViewController. Updated!