# Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x10426be10)

Tags: ios, swift

i am very new to coding and i am doing a tutorial but I keep on getting this bug. Not sure what to do. I have been looking for answers for over an hour. Hope anyone here can help thanks.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)!
    let contact = self.contacts[indexPath.row]
    let destination = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
    destination.contact = contact
}
```

My MainStoryBoard:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688834/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uinavigationcontroller-to-jacrs-ios-topviewcontr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier" {

 let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)! 
 let contact = self.contacts[indexPath.row] 
 let destination = segue.destination as! UINavigationController 
 let vc = destination.topViewController as! DetailViewController 
 vc.contact = contact 

    }
 }
```

Also make sure your segue `identifier` is defined

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your segue is trying to show a `UINavigationController` with inside your `DetailViewController`.
Try to do that:

```
let destination = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).rootViewController as! DetailViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
let destination = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
```

You are trying to cast `UINavigationController` to `DetailViewController`. This cannot be accomplished. `DetailViewController` (from your screenshot) is managed by `UINavigationController`, which is a direct destination in your case.

So the best practice would be wrapping your initial controller into `UINavigationController`, i.e. just make Navigation Controller the starting point of your app and then draw segue from table to `DetailViewController` (not into intermediate navigation controller). After that, your code will be working just fine.